# Longest Palindrome in integer array

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, dev-c++

I want to find the largest palindrome in an integer array. I tried making my own algorithm and not looking at the online ones. But this is not working. I tried doing debugging but couldn't get it to work.

**Sample input:**

"1367611342142412431113424823782"

Output: 113421424124311

```
void palindrome()
{
    int max = 0;
    int len;
    int start;
    int end;
    int st=0,en=0;
    bool palin = false;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=size-1; j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(array[i] == array[j])
            {
                start = i;
                end = j;
                while(j==i+1 || j+1 == i || j == i )
                {
                    if(array[i] == array[j])
                    {
                        i++; 
                        j--;
                        palin = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        palin = false;
                        break;  
                    }
                }
                i= start;
                j= end;
            }
            if(palin == true)
                {
                    len = end - start;
                    if(len>max)
                    {
                        cout<<" "<<st<<" "<<en<<endl;
                        st=i;
                        en =j;
                        max = len;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<st<<" "<<en<<endl;
    ofstream file("output.txt");
    for(int i=st;i<=en;i++)
    {
        file<<array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: expected output is 113421424124311

Comment: I tried to debug so problem is that in the while loop the values get zero which should continue from the last postion

Answer (score 1):

There is solution

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Result
{   
    int fromIndex, toIndex;
    Result(int fromIndex, int toIndex){
        this->fromIndex = fromIndex;
        this->toIndex = toIndex;
    }

    int length(){
        return toIndex - fromIndex;
    }
};

bool isPalindrome(std::string &s, int left, int right){
    while(left <= right){
        if(s[left] != s[right]){
            return false;
        }
        left ++;
        right --;
    }
    return true;
}

std::string solve(std::string &s){
    int startIndex = 0;
    int toIndex = s.size() - 1;
    Result result(0,0);
    while(true){
        if(isPalindrome(s, startIndex, toIndex)){
            if(result.length() < (toIndex - startIndex)){
                result.fromIndex = startIndex;
                result.toIndex = toIndex;
            }
        }
        toIndex --;
        if(toIndex <= startIndex){
            toIndex = s.size() - 1;
            startIndex++;
        }
        if(startIndex == s.size() - 1){
            break;
        }
    }

    std::string str = "";
    for (int i = result.fromIndex; i <= result.toIndex; ++i)
    {
        str += s[i];
    }

    return str;

}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "1367611342142412431113424823782";
    std::string result = solve(s);
    std::cout << "Longest palindrome is: "<< result;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in more structural way. Split your task in to sub-tasks first. In this case there are to sub-tasks:
    1. go over all possible combinations
    2. check if this combination is a palindrome. 
Each task is another function - this way it is easier to think, read code and debug.
(In case you want to write it to file - it is a third task!)

Here is the code for the "go over all possible combinations". I guess you will find yourself how to check a single array if it is a palindrome.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int* arr, int size);
bool findLargestPalindrome(int* arr, int size);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,3,6,7,6,1,1,3,4,2,1,4,2,4,1,2,4,3,1,1,1,3,4,2,4,8,2,3,7,8,2 };
    int arrSize = 31;

    findLargestPalindrome(arr, arrSize);
}

bool findLargestPalindrome(int* arr, int size)
{
    for (int testSize = size; testSize > 0; testSize--)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;
        while (testSize + startIndex <= size)
        {
            int* arrayToTest = &(arr[startIndex]);
            if (isPalindrome(arr, testSize))
            {
                //TODO: you found it - do with it whatever you want
                return true;
            }
            startIndex++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool isPalindrome(int* arr, int size)
{
    //TODO: your code for single palindrome
    return false;
}
```